# Whether the MySQL JDBC parameter(utf8mb4_general_ci) is set properly

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I set a field of a table in mysql to **utf8mb4_general_ci** by the following sql

```sql
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE FieldName VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

But my application still doesn't support emoji.So I want to add a JDBC parameter

```
connectionCollation=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

The problem is that I don't know if my application will report an error, since I didn't set the entire table or the entire database here.

The variables of database are

```
mysql> show variables where variable_name like "col%";
+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_general_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Are you using `charset=utf8mb4` in your connection URL?

Comment: no. I tried to add __connectionCollation=utf8mb4_general_ci__ today, and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add connectionCollation=utf8mb4_general_ci today, and it works.